# IUPAC name of this compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

Please solve this question .I hope its name is $1-$Tertiary amino cyclopentanone. But it have some mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

Cyclic amides of amino carboxylic acids are called **lactams.**

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* lactames can be named by two methods:

> **P-66.1.5.1** Lactams and lactims
>
> Intramolecular amides of amino carboxylic acids, $\ce{-CO-NH-{}}$, are called ‘lactams’ and their tautomers, $\ce{-C(OH)=N-{}}$, are ‘lactims’. Lactams are named in two ways:
>
> (1) as heterocyclic pseudo ketones;
>
> (2) by substituting ‘lactam’ for the ‘ic acid’ ending of a systematic ‘oic acid’ name for the parent acid without the amino substituent, and inserting a locant designating the position of the amino group between the ‘o’ and ‘lactam’. Lactims are named in the same way, using ‘lactim’ in place of ‘lactam’.
>
> Method (1) generates preferred IUPAC names.

The corresponding heterocyclic parent structure is **piperidine.**

[image: piperidine]

Thus, the preferred IUPAC name for the lactam according to Method (1) is the pseudo ketone **piperidin-2-one.**

[image: piperidin-2-one]

The systematic name of the parent acid without the amino substituent is **pentanoic acid.**

[image: pentanoic acid]

Therefore, the lactam can also be named as **pentano-5-lactam** in accordance with Method (2).